# Java Tooklit having problems grabbing updated caps lock status

Tags: java, keyboard

I am using Java's toolkit package (java.awt.Toolkit and import java.awt.event.KeyEvent) to check the caps lock status. I however, cannot update the caps lock status. It seems to grab the caps lock instance only once, and stays in that position. So for example, in this code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    boolean temp = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
    System.out.print(temp + " ,");
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
}
```

It should theoretically check 10 times, every 1 second. So for example, if my caps lock is on during the first 5 seconds, and off during the last 5 seconds, then the console should output

```
true, true, true, true, true, false, false, false, false, false,
```

However, what my code does, is just grab what my caps lock key is like when it first enters the for loop, and stay that way, regaurdless of wether I turn it off or on afterwards.

So for example, if I keep my caps lock on for the first 5 seconds, and off the last 5 secs, like above, it will output

```
true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true,
```

or if I keep my caps lock key off the first 5 seconds then on the last 5 secs, it will output

false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false,
Anyone know how to fix this so it dynamically updates the keypress status?

Thanks!

Comment: Unable to reproduce in isolation; please verify that you are not ignoring exceptions, and [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that shows your approach.